# Android Studio MainActivity marking red error. Noob

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi pretty new to android studio and I 'm getting this error can someone help out. I can't figure out exactly how to solve this error. it says that MainActivity is an unresolved class

activity_main.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andriod.justjava.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="QUANTITY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="$0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="Order" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error shows in

```
`    tools:context="com.example.andriod.justjava.MainActivity">
`
```

THanks for your help!

Comment: Is that the correct package?  Try changing it to just this: `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is it, but you misspelled "android":

```
tools:context="com.example.andriod.justjava.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you put the incorrect package name? Try change it.

Or do you add this activity to the manifest file?